# javafx передача данных между диалогами

Tags: javafx

Есть два диалога 
Как передать какое - либо значение из *диалога2* в *диалог1*
пробую так:
В диалоге 1:

```
 public void setCategory(String kateg) {
    System.out.println(kateg);
    pmk_id.setText(kateg);

}
```

в диалоге 2:

```
public void kategTreeMouseClick(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        int click = mouseEvent.getClickCount();
        if (click == 2) {
            TreeItem<pmk_category> kateg =kategTree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            addToPMKController addCategory = new addToPMKController();
            addCategory.setCategory(kateg.getValue().getCategory());
            dialogStage.close();
        }
    }
```

В итоге значение передается, но не отображается в *TextField*, хотя в  `System.out.println(kateg);` я вижу передаваемое значение.

Подскажите что не так.

Comment: Возможно не `FX` поток. Попробуйте `Platform.runLater( () -> pmk_id.setText(kateg) );`